# Is there any way to pass SESSION id through the anchor tag when the user clicks on it?

Tags: php, session

I want to pass a unique session for each link that user clicks on, something like this:-

```php
$sql = "select * from modulestb where teacherid=?";
$st = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$st->execute(array($_SESSION['logid']));
foreach ($st as $row) {
    $_SESSION['stage'] = $row['stage'];
    $_SESSION['mid']   = $row['mid'];
    echo "<a style='color:white;'  href=report.php?>" . $row['name'] . " (Stage :" . $row['stage'] . "</a>";
}
```

As an example:

[image: As this image]

Comment: What do you want to store in every unique session?

Comment: I want to store Id and stage of each module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this code but I hope you understand the concept :-)

```
<?php
//Always use this preferbly at the start of the script 
//when dealing with sessions in PHP
session_start();

//If data isset and contains anything
if (!empty($_GET['data'])) {    
    $data = unserialize($data);  //Restore to the array  
    $id = $data['mid'];

    //Set the actual session based on what user has clicked on
    //If user has clicked on mid 1 , this will store $_SESSION['module1'] = value of stage
    //If user has clicked on mid 2 , this will store $_SESSION['module2'] = value of stage
    //etc
    $_SESSION['module'.$id] = $data['stage'];
}

$sql = "select * from modulestb where teacherid=?";
$st = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$st->execute(array($_SESSION['logid']));
foreach ($st as $row) {
    //Serialize the data you want to save into your session
    //(Make the array a string that represents the array)
    $data = serialize(array('stage'=>$row['stage'],
                  'mid' => $row['mid']));

    echo "<a style='color:white;'  href=report.php?data=$data>" . $row['name'] . " (Stage :" . 
    $row['stage'] . "</a>";
}
```